# Setting monitor power state in python?

Tags: python, winapi

How can I send a monitor into/out-of a different power state (like sleep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this article:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/screen/scmonitorpower.htm

It appears you need to send a SendMessage call similar to:

SendMessage(Me.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, ByVal MONITOR_OFF)

Although, that is a VB version. What you're really after is the WinAPI call, I'm sure you can convert this bit to however you invoke WinAPI calls in Python. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32gui
import win32con

if argument == "on":
  win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                       win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)

if argument == "off":
  win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                       win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)

if argument == "sleep":
  win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                       win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 1)
```

Comment: I noticed that param -1 = on won't turn on the monitor when the energy setting timeout has been reached. In that case the monitors will get powered on, but before they are really on, they get turned off automatically by the os again. In that case it would be the best to emulate a mouse move, key press or something like that